# Google cloud platform upload image in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload image to firebase storage in node.js using google platform API, and here is my code:

```
function upload_file(filename, buffer) {
    let file = bucket.file(filename);
    console.log(`file created: ${filename}`);
    file.save(buffer)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`${filename} should be in bucket now`);
        return file.bucket.upload(filename);
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(`upload succeed: ${filename}`);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And here is the output:

```
file created: 7CD5F2FA-CB2F-4014-BB65-3BBC3D8B3254.jpg
7CD5F2FA-CB2F-4014-BB65-3BBC3D8B3254.jpg should be in bucket now
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '7CD5F2FA-CB2F-4014-BB65-3BBC3D8B3254.jpg'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '7CD5F2FA-CB2F-4014-BB65-3BBC3D8B3254.jpg' }
```

I checked my bucket, and I did found the image I just uploaded. However, the error said the file cannot be found. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing to me.  It looks like it's trying to upload twice.

First, you're calling [file.save()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/File#save), which is documented as:

> Write arbitrary data to a file.
>
> This is a convenience method which wraps File#createWriteStream.

Then you're calling [bucket.upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/Bucket#upload), which is documented as:

> Upload a file to the bucket. This is a convenience method that wraps
>   File#createWriteStream.

So, what I'm taking away is that you're calling File#createWriteStream twice.  That doesn't make sense.

Also, this code doesn't make sense:

```
return file.bucket.upload(filename);
```

Since File doesn't have a property called `bucket`.  I would expect this code to fail simply on that fact.

I think it's time to study the Cloud Storage APIs a bit more to make sure you're doing the right thing.